# Edit Gridview update issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspxgridview

I have got a gridview which when you press select on a row it transfers you to another gridview page,
which displays more columns from that table to give more detail about that row.

I know how to do this using:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="MISAppID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ApplicationsDetails.aspx?MISAppID={0}" Text="Select" />
```

In the 1st Gridview then using a Stored-procedure on the second page it displays the correct row using the ID field.

In my current site on the second page, I have added an edit button that does edit the row correctly in my database but on completion, it breaks the site and I can't work out how to get it to just refresh the gridview

This is the error I get:

> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Updating is not
> supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless UpdateCommand is
> specified.

Is it the case that my BindGrid is missing something or is the way I am using my Stored-procedure?

Here is my VB code:

```
Public Sub BindGrid() Handles SqlDataSource1.Selecting

End Sub



Protected Sub OnRowEditing(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    Dim misappId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values(0))
    Dim application As String = TryCast(row.Cells(2).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim url As String = TryCast(row.Cells(3).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim access_group As String = TryCast(row.Cells(4).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim creator_ein As String = TryCast(row.Cells(5).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim data_location As String = TryCast(row.Cells(6).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim purpose As String = TryCast(row.Cells(7).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim active As String = TryCast(row.Cells(8).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim business_owner As String = TryCast(row.Cells(9).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    Dim area As String = TryCast(row.Cells(10).Controls(0), TextBox).Text

    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myLocalConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
         Using cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_AutomationCompassApplications SET Application = @Application, URL = @URL, Access_Group = @Access_Group, Creator_EIN = @Creator_EIN, Data_location = @Data_location, Purpose = @Purpose,         Active = @Active, Business_Owner = @Business_Owner, Area = @Area WHERE MISAppID = @MISAppID")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MISAppID", misappId)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Application", application)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", url)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Access_Group", access_group)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Creator_EIN", creator_ein)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data_location", data_location)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", purpose)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", active)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business_Owner", business_owner)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Area", area)

            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, say we have a list of hotels - we want to display them, and then click on a row to eit.

(and you writing WAY too much code here).

So, lets say we drop in a gridview. Use the connection wizard - let it generate the markup.
THEN REMOVE the data source on the page, remove the datasource property of the gridview.

So, in less time then it takes me to write above? We have this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="Edit"
                            PK = '<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Note the cool trick I used to get the PK row index.

When you are looking at the grid, you can't double click on the button to wire up a event (code behind), but you CAN DO THIS!!!!

[image]

Note VERY care full in above - I typed in OnClick "=", when you HIT "=", then NOTE the inteli-sense that popped up - the create NEW event is what we need. Click on create new event - NOTHING seems to happen, but if we NOW go to code behind, we have a code stub for the button!!!

And note how I needed/wanted the PK row value - so I just shoved in and created my OWN custom attribute for that button. ("PK").

Ok, so our code to load up the grid is now this - and I included the button click code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * from tblHotels Order by HotelName"

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Dim MyTable As New DataTable
        MyTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable
        GridView1.DataBind()

        Session("MyTable") = MyTable
    End Using

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim MyBtn As Button = sender

    Session("RowID") = MyBtn.Attributes.Item("PK")

    Response.Redirect("~/EditHotel.aspx")


End Sub
```

Look how clean and simple the above is!!! I find this as easy say as MS-Access coding!!!

Ok, so the grid now looks like this:

[image]

Note the button click code.

So, our markup is this for the new page (to edit hte ONE row).

```
<div style="float:left;width:20%">

    <div style="text-align:right">
        First Name :<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstname" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        Last Name :<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastname" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        Hotel Name :<asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        City  :<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        Active :<asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:CheckBox>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both">
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server"   Text ="Save " />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Style="margin-left:20px" />

</div>

</form>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

and the load code and save button code for this page?

This:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        LoadInfo()
    End If
End Sub


Sub LoadInfo()

    Dim MyTable As DataTable = Session("MyTable")
    Dim MyRow As DataRow = MyTable.Rows(Session("RowID"))

    txtFirstname.Text = MyRow("FirstName")
    txtLastname.Text = MyRow("LastName")
    txtCity.Text = MyRow("City")
    txtHotel.Text = MyRow("HotelName")
    Active.Checked = MyRow("Active")

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    Dim MyTable As DataTable = Session("MyTable")

    Dim MyRow As DataRow = MyTable.Rows(Session("RowID"))

    MyRow("FirstName") = txtFirstname.Text
    MyRow("LastName") = txtLastname.Text
    MyRow("City") = txtCity.Text
    MyRow("HotelName") = txtHotel.Text
    MyRow("Active") = Active.Checked

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels where ID = 0",
                New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
        Dim cmdUpdate As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

        da.Update(MyTable)

    End Using

    Response.Redirect("~/MyTours.aspx")

End Sub
```

Again, look how easy, clean and readable the code is.

Study the above example - you see that you don't need all that parameters code, and you see how little code is in fact required to select a row - jump to page to edit, and then you hit save - update the data and jump back to the grid row page.